# What is this fruit / nut?

Tags: species-identification, botany, seeds

These were found in a park in Pittsburgh, PA. From a distance they looked almost like plums, but they're actually hollow, paper-like covers that contain a hard pea-sized seed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the good description of the fruit, but could you also give an approximate size? And was it a tree or a shrub that you found them on?

Comment: Thanks for your edit in astronomy but I could use all your up votes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely a member of the genus *Staphylea*. Since you are in Pittsburgh, PA, it's most likely [*Staphylea trifolia* L.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staphylea_trifolia), or an introduced species.

Comment: That is it! I've never heard of (or seen) a "bladdernut" before.

Answer (score -1):

By the looks Of it,it mostly is a ***hop hornbeam*** Which are indeed found in pittsburgh
But i Still cant confirm it because 
**they are no photos of their leaves and any twigs or the whole tree, this info would be great to identify it** and do you mind mentioning the name of the park you've been to
Can you confirm whether the tree looked like this
[image: Ostrya virginis]
**Ostrya Virginis**

Comment: Nope, definetly not an *Ostrya* species.